# Facing issues with NgModel and [checked] for a radio input

Tags: angular, angular-forms

So I'm working with submitting a angular form and i giving an option to update the data to the user ,But I'm not able to pre-check the radio button based on a condition when the input filed is binded with ngModel ,I'm a absolute beginner to angular so any help would be appreciated

***app.component.html***

```
<form #office="ngForm">
<div class="form-group pointer">
              <label for="Shift" class="font-weight-bold fs-6">Tansport <span class="text-danger">*</span></label><br>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input pointer" [checked]="editableData.transport.indexOf('cab') > -1" type="radio" ngModel  name="transport" id="transport-1" value="cab">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="transport-1">Cab</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <input class="form-check-input pointer" [checked]="editableData.transport.indexOf('own') > -1" type="radio" ngModel name="transport" id="transport-2" value="own">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="transport-2" >Own</label>
                </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

[image]

One of the checkbox needs to be checked based on a condition

Comment: do you see any error in console? can provide a stackblitz?

Comment: No console errors ,please check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-osbxr6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html ,the problem is the checkbox is not getting checked based on the condition in checked ,if i remove ngModel it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it here :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vb5eeh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

binded it with an object from class.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kylv5c

Why do you need this ngModel on radioButton though? If you want to access their value you can use the form value as well.

Comment: when i hit submit button i get no value with the above stackblitz

Comment: check again. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t8ntp4
I've added come  comments explaining the changes.